# Geometric interpretation of a Taylor series like identity

Tags: taylor-expansion

Johann Bernoulli published (something like) the following expression in his journal Acta Eruditorum.

$\int_0^x f(t) dt = xf(x)-\frac{x^2}{2!}f'(x)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f''(x)-\frac{x^4}{4!}f'''(x)+...$

Is there a geometric interpretation of this identity? That is can each term on the right side be interpreted as an area of sorts and all of them taken together as being the area under the curve of $f(t)$ from $0$ to $x$?

Comment: you probably mean $f(0)$, BTW doesn't the interpretation work??

Comment: Are you aware of the derivation of the formula by repeated integration by parts? That yields what might be called a geometric interpretation, though it's probably not quite as geometric as you'd like it to be: The area under $f$ is the area under $(xf)'$ minus the area under $xf'$, which in turn is the area under $(\frac12x^2f')'$ minus the area under $\frac12x^2f''$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As Joriki commented, this is just repeated integration by parts. Let us start considering $\int f(t)~dt$ and use $u=f(t)$ and $v'=dt$; these lead to $u'=f'(t)~dt$,$v=t$. So $$\int f(t)~dt= tf(t)-\int t f'(t)~dt$$ Now, for the second integral, integration by parts again with $u=f'(t)$,$v'=t~dt$; these lead to $u'=f''(t)~dt$,$v=\frac{t^2}{2}$. So,$$\int t f'(t)~dt=\frac{t^2}{2}f'(t)-\frac{1}{2}\int t^2 f''(t)~dt$$ Let us repeat once more with $u=f''(t)$,$v'=t^2~dt$; these lead to $u'=f'''(t)~dt$,$v=\frac{t^3}{3}$. So,$$\int t^2 f'(t)~dt=\frac{t^3}{3}f''(t)-\frac{1}{3}\int t^3 f'''(t)~dt$$ and so on.

So, the antiderivative becomes $$\int f(t) dt = tf(t)-\frac{t^2}{2!}f'(t)+\frac{t^3}{3!}f''(t)-\frac{t^4}{4!}f'''(t)+...$$ and then the value of the integral between bounds $0$ and $x$ you wrote after Bernoulli.

Concerning a "geometric" interpretation, since each integral corresponds to the area between a curve and the $x$ axis, the final formula gives a sum of areas (again, as Joriki commented)